Expo Audio createAsync() returns a Sound with functions set to undefined
Running my Expo app in Chrome on Mac, the code below fails on the playAsync call with "TypeError: sound.playAsync is not a function".
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
        staysActiveInBackground: true,
        interruptionModeAndroid: InterruptionModeAndroid.DuckOthers,
        shouldDuckAndroid: false,
        playThroughEarpieceAndroid: false,
      });
      await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      const { sound, status } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync({ uri: audioFullUrl });
      this.sound = sound;
      this.sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate((status: AVPlaybackStatus) => {
        if (status.didJustFinish) {
          console.log('Sound finished playing');
          this.sound?.unloadAsync();
        }
      });
      await sound.playAsync();

The debugger reveals that the SoundObject sound object has the function names, but they're all set to undefined. What could be the cause of this?
Additional info: I don't think the requestPermissionsAsync nor setAudioModeAsync are necessary, but I added them while trying to diagnose this just to test. The library code in createAsync creates the object with a simple new Sound(), and the functions are defined with Object.assign(Sound.prototype, PlaybackMixin);. There aren't any conditions around the loading or permissions.

Since the mixin is not being applied correctly, a workaround is to call the mixin function directly:
await PlaybackMixin.playAsync.call(sound);
